# Swift - What is the replacement for UIButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted in iOS 15?

Tags: swift, uikit

Code:

```
self.muteButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
```

Error:

```
'showsTouchWhenHighlighted' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: This property is ignored when using UIButtonConfiguration
```

I am looking for the replacement for this function.  I have looked through the button properties and I can't find anything that would directly match it.

Comment: You can still use it with a Default style button... it's *ignored when using **`UIButtonConfiguration`***